# if data = null error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: arrays, database, laravel

I'm will insert arrays into the database. If there is information, it will not error.
I try to find a solution to brush the brush from this site. But it was not successful.

this is my code

controller

```
 $new = new Checks();
    $new->nvr_id = Input::get('nvr_id');
    $new->check_date = Input::get('check_date');
    $new->status_record = Input::get('check_record');
    $new->status_hdd = Input::get('check_hdd');
    $new->status_camera = Input::get('check_camera');
    $new->comment = Input::get('comment');
    $new->save();
    $id = $new->id;
    $issue[] = Input::get('issue');
    if ($issue == null) {

    } elseif (!empty($issue)) {
        foreach ($issue as $item) {
            foreach ($item as $item1) {
                addIssues::create([
                    'check_id' => $id,
                    'issue_id' => $item1
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

create.blade.php

```
<select name="issue[]" id="issue" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($issue as $key => $item) 
        <option value = "{{ $key }}" > { { $item } } < /option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

database relationship

issue  1 to m  addIssues m to 1 check

Comment: dd contents of $issue after line $issue[] = Input::get('issue'); to ensure that what you get is an array.

Comment: can you show us the output of dd(Input::get('issue')); ?

Comment: dd(Input::get('issue'));
if select tags
 array:1 [▼
  0 => "1"
]
if no tags = null

Comment: i can not success process if $issue = null

Comment: i need code skip "if (!empty($issue)) {
            foreach ($issue as $item) {
                foreach ($item as $item1) {
                    addIssues::create([
                        'check_id' => $id,
                        'issue_id' => $item1
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }"
if $issue = null

Answer (score 0):

Change the create.blade.php code to this

```
<select name="issue[]" id="issue" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
  @if(count($issue))
    @foreach($issue as $key => $item) 
        <option value = "{{ $key }}" > { { $item } } < /option>
    @endforeach
  @endif
</select>
```

The `@if` construct will handle the error.

Comment: still error = Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: What is the complete controller code for the `create` function?

Comment: $data = Nvrs::find($id);
        $issue = Issues::where('done', '=', 'Open')
            ->pluck('order', 'id');
        //dd($issue);
        return view('checks.create', compact('data', 'issue'));